# Error response when POSTing JSON with PERL

Tags: json, perl, post

I wrote a small PERL script to fetch some data from an URL using PERL. Not being an experienced programmer, I used the examples I found here in Stackoverflow. However, I always get the response

{"error":{"code":2,"message":"post parameter request missing"}}

The script looks like this

```
my $uri = 'URL';
my $json = '{"sourceCountry":"DE","sourceStore":476,"targetCountry":"DE","targetStore":[869],"article":[110101]}';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$response = $lwp->request($req);
```

The  complete response is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 14:29:06 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 63
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Client-Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2014 14:29:06 GMT
Client-Peer: 10.200.10.74:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3

{"error":{"code":2,"message":"post parameter request missing"}}
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: telling us what the URL is would probably be extremely helpful.

Comment: The ULS is an internal one, so I may not communicate it. The information I recieved from the developer of the service is, that I should POST the following JSON object {
    "sourceCountry": "DE",
    "sourceStore": 476,
    "targetCountry": "DE",
    "targetStore": [
        869
    ],
    "article": [
        110101
    ]
} I added the complete response above

Comment: Is it a [JSON RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) service? (That is the error I would expect from such a service)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common 'POST';
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$lwp->request( POST $uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content' => $json );
```

though that should do basically the same thing except also setting Content-Length.

Alternatively, if the error you mention is literally indicating there is supposed to be a POST parameter (aka form data parameter) named request, try:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common 'POST';
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$lwp->request( POST $uri, [ 'request' => $json ] );
```

Comment: If the URL is expecting form data, then the `Content-Type` should probably be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`.

Comment: Sounds like it. Of course, we have no way of knowing what parameter name to use.

Comment: YOur first idea changes nothing to the response from the POST. Your second idea did not run, it throws an error in PERL

Comment: what error?  did you use HTTP::Request::Common and import POST?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is a [JSON RPC 2](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) service that you are trying to contact, you are missing part of the structure.

```
my $json = '{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":1,
  "method":"some-method",
  "params":{"sourceCountry":"DE","sourceStore":476,"targetCountry":"DE","targetStore":[869],"article":[110101]}
}';
```

---

If it is a [JSON RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) service you could use [JSON::RPC::LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::RPC::LWP); which combines [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) and [JSON::RPC::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::RPC::Common). It uses [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) so there will be quite a few dependencies to install. ( It uses [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) because [JSON::RPC::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::RPC::Common) uses [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose). )

```
use JSON::RPC::LWP;
my $url = ...;

my $rpc = JSON::RPC::LWP->new(
  agent => 'Example ',
);

my $response = $rpc->call(
  $url, # uri
  'some-method', # service
   {
     sourceCountry => "DE",
     sourceStore   => 476,
     targetCountry => "DE",
     targetStore   => [869],
     article       => [110101],
   } # JSON container
);

if( my $error = $response->error ){
  print 'error: #', $error->code, ' "', $error->message, "\"\n";
}else{
  print "success!\n";
  use Data::Dumper;
  print Dumper( $response->result );
}
```

Note that you don't give [JSON::RPC::LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::RPC::LWP) a JSON string, you give it a data structure.